# Protetor de link em PHP para capturar e Criptografar e adicionar uma URL antes

Tags: php, html5, base64

Ola gostaria de saber como posso usar JavaScript ou PHP para colocar essa url `https://protetor.com/?url=` antes dos endereços dos servidores de download automaticamente eu uso esses servidores SkyDrive, Clouddrive, Pcloud, Bitcasa, Meocloud, LolaBits, Google, Clouddriver eu usava o Adfly ele possui um script em JavaScript que adiciona o endereço automaticamente no inicio destas URLs o endereço do protetor. Com tudo esse novo protetor não dispoem essa especie de scripts.

> UM EXEMPLO EM **jQuery**:

```
// Lista de bases de URLs dos servidores.
var urlsBases = ["meocloud.pt", "mega.co.nz", "outro.servidor.com"];

for (var i = 0; i < urlsBases.length; i++) {
var serverUrlBase = urlsBases[i];

// OBS: é necessário colocar entre aspas simples a url no filtro do jQuery 
por atributo.
$("a[href*='" + serverUrlBase + "']").each(function() {
    var urlProtegida = "https://protetor.com/?url=" + 
$(this).attr("href");

    $(this).attr("href", urlProtegida);
});
}
```

> Mas tem alguma forma em ***PHP*** para codificar a url ? no final ? em
>   base 64

EXEMPLO:

`https://protetor.com/?url=aHR0cHM6Ly91cGxvYWRici5jb20vOTBmZTExODRmZTkxNzBhNA==`

> Para descodificar eu já sei, porem não pra codificar... Alguém sabe
>   como ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para converter um valor para *Base64*, no *JavaScript*, basta utilizar a função `window.btoa`, por exemplo: `btoa($(this).attr("href")`

**Exemplo:**

```js
/**
 * Executa a função após criação. Isso dispensará o uso do jQuery
 * dessa forma você poderá chamar, antes mesmos das execuções de
 * outros scripts.
 */
(() => {
  const urlsBases = ["meocloud.pt", "mega.co.nz", "outro.com"];

  for (let urlBase of urlsBases) {

    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='" + urlBase + "']");

    anchors.forEach(el => {
      let urlProtegida = "https://protetor.com/?url=" + btoa(el.getAttribute("href"))

      el.setAttribute("href", urlProtegida)

      console.log(urlProtegida)
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<a href="https://meocloud.pt/sdashdasda">meocloud<a>
<a href="https://mega.co.nz/hfghfghf">mega<a>
<a href="https://outro.com/121">outro<a>
```

No *PHP*, você pode usar a função `base64_encode`. Ela irá converter uma *string* para a codificação *base64*, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$urls = [
    "https://meocloud.pt/sdashdasda",
    "https://mega.co.nz/hfghfghf",
    "https://outro.servidor.com/1gfdg5d4",
];

foreach($urls as $url) {
    echo "https://protetor.com/?url=" . base64_encode($url), PHP_EOL;
}
```

<sup>Demonstração: https://ideone.com/j2KR3V</sup>

Comment: No php, tem como fazer ele pegar as url automaticamente como no javascript ?

Comment: @MatheusVitor Não é possível manipular o HTML com o PHP. É possível manipular caso essas URL venham de um banco de dados. Aí é possível manipular antes, porém antes do HTML ser carregado.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou!